# jQuery UI position utility for elements in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, position

I am using jQuery UI position utility to place markers on an image map. I am using html5 data attributes on each area tag in the map and then, when a user clicks on a link that contains the same data attribute as one of the areas, it generates the html for the marker. This is working correctly.

However, a link can correspond to different area tags. So I have created an array of the DOM elements and appended them to a div on the page.  Then, when I try to use the position utility on each marker, all of the markers in the array end up in the same position rather than on the area tag that matches its data attribute.  I'm guessing this has something to do with appending the array rather than raw DOM objects?

Here is my code below:

```
var $holder = $('#holder'); //div that holds the generated markers
    var $map = $('#floorPlan');
    var $area = $('#floorPlan area');
    $('.locationLink li a').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            //remove pinned markers
            $holder.children('.pinned').fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            var grp = $(this).attr('data-group'),
                $grpMatch = new Array();

            //generate new markers and match to area
            $map.find('area[data-group="' + grp + '"]').each(function () {
                var loc = $(this).attr('data-loc')
                // create a marker for each matched area and create array
                if ($(this).hasClass('hall')) {
                    var eleItems = '<div data-loc="' + loc + '" data-group="' + grp + '" class="marker marker-blue"></div>';
                }
                else {
                    var eleItems = '<div data-loc="' + loc + '" data-group="' + grp + '" class="marker"></div>';
                }

                $grpMatch.push(eleItems);
                 $holder.append($grpMatch);
                positionMarker();

            });

            return false;
        });

    });


    function positionMarker() {


        $holder.children('.marker').each(function() {
            var $lMarker = $(this);
            var mLoc = $lMarker.attr('data-loc');
            var $aMatch = $map.find('area[data-loc="' + mLoc + '"]');

            $lMarker.position({
                'my': 'center center',
                'at': 'center center',
                'of': $aMatch,
                'collision': 'none'
            }).addClass('pinned');

        });
    }
```

Thanks for the help